# Map fluid motion with the latest mapbox (1.6.2) API, how to achieve?

Tags: javascript, css, dictionary, mapbox, motion

Once it was possible to achieve the fluid motion with Easing Mapbox methods

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v0.6.7/#mapbox.ease

but the latest API have changed dramatically, is it be possible to achieve the smooth map motion with the modern API?

Using of the old version, still stable 0.6.*, is not the case since a lot of new features are very useful.

Answer (score 1):

@mourner mentioned this in his last blog post; Leaflet 0.8 should include this and the pull request still [appears to be open](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/2382). You may be able to use the 0.8-dev branch to get the [map.zoomPanTo](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/1413) animations with this.

Answer (score 0):

I've found some discussion on leaflet: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/1617
That suggests this call

```
map.setView({ lat, lon }, 15, { 
  pan: { animate: true }, 
  zoom: { animate: true } 
});
```

But after checking source of `setView` function it seems that setView is trying to smooth transit when the next point is one window close to the previous

```
map.setView({ lat, lon}, 15);
```

Useful links

- `LatLng()`: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.1/l-latlng/
- `panTo()`: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v1.6.1/l-map-class/#map-set-methods